# Spring change application.properties location using mvn clean install

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, properties-file

Im a bit confused about this.

Im creating a script that build my project, but I need to specify the location of the application properties while using `mvn clean install`.
There exists something like `mvn clean install -propLocation=/some_path/application.properties`?

Comment: Why do you mean by `but I need to specify the location of the application properties`? There are two options either the `application.properteis` is in `src/main/resources` which means it will be packaged into the resulting application or the `application.properties` is outside the build (which is the best) and that means you don't need to specify it for the build...

Comment: Yeah I want an external application properties, but I also want to specify his location when using "mvn clean install" so at the end I have Server.jar that use /some/path/application.properties when needed. But for reasons, it need to be specified during the build process

Comment: You can define an external configuration via command for spring boot applications https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config